# My daughter taken a photo of a species

Tags: species

[image][image]
My daughter is studying in 4 the std. She is interested in species related study. Pls guide her.

Comment: For identification it is helpful to add information, where in the world and which habitat you found the animal/plant. Also the size could be useful. Could you please edit your question to add these information? And while your at it, maybe change the title to '_... photo of a beetle_'

Comment: And is your question about identifying this particular animal, or is this one just an example and you want to generally know, how to identify animals by yourself? Could you please clarify this?

Comment: And please reduce the size of your images before posting. On my browser the 0.3 Mb image (2000 px wide to fit a 600 px space) only shows in black. A quarter of the size is more than adequate.